# Python 3.8 pandas *.csv import into MSSQL

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, csv

It should not that be difficult to import some data from a `.csv` file and I have done it already. But then I got a file with some data and it stores 50k of lines and in a really confusing way. I'm unable to import that one and I would like to reach out for help.

Problem one: everything is stored in `row.name` but it should be stored in `row.name, row.id, row.year` and so on.

Problem two: I'm not allowed to modify the `.csv` file.

Here are the first line of the `.csv` file:

```
name,id,nametype,recclass,mass (g),fall,year,reclat,reclong,GeoLocation
"Aachen,1,Valid,L5,21,Fell,1880,50.775,6.08333,""(50.775000, 6.083330)"""
"Aarhus,2,Valid,H6,720,Fell,1951,56.18333,10.23333,""(56.183330, 10.233330)"""
"Abee,6,Valid,EH4,107000,Fell,1952,54.21667,-113,""(54.216670, -113.000000)"""
"Acapulco,10,Valid,Acapulcoite,1914,Fell,1976,16.88333,-99.9,""(16.883330, -99.900000)"""
"Achiras,370,Valid,L6,780,Fell,1902,-33.16667,-64.95,""(-33.166670, -64.950000)"""
"Adhi Kot,379,Valid,EH4,4239,Fell,1919,32.1,71.8,""(32.100000, 71.800000)"""
```

Here is my Python script to import above `.csv` file

```
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc
import DatabaseConnectionDetails as dcd # seperate file to import DB settings

#Get the file loaded in the memory
data = pd.read_csv (r'C:\pathToTHeFileLocation\MeteoriteDataShort.csv', delimiter=',')
col_names =['name', 'id', 'nametype', 'recclass', 'mass (g)', 'fall', 'year', 'reclat', 'reclong', 'GeoLocation']
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=col_names)

#establish connection to MsSqldb
conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                      'Server=' + dcd.DB_SERVER + ';'
                      'Database=' + dcd.DB_DB + ';'
                      'Trusted_Connection=' + dcd.TRUSTED_CONNECTION + ';')
cursor = conn.cursor()

#Insert into Table
for row in df.itertuples():
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO Meteorite.dbo.MeteoriteDataPoints (MeteoriteName, MeteoriteId, NameType, RecClass, MassInG, FallStatus, FellYear, RecLatitude, RecLongitude, Geolocation) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)',
                row.name
                ,row.id
                ,row.nametype
                ,row.recclass
                ,row._5
                ,row.fall
                ,row.year
                ,row.reclat
                ,row.reclong
                ,row.GeoLocation
                )
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

It would be really nice if someone can teach me or show me my mistakes.

Comment: Remove all the sql part, it's just added stuff that doesn't reproduce your problem. The issue is in how you're loading the data to `pandas`. The rows have some extra quotation marks which have to be handled, because the delimiter `,` is actually not found (is inside the quotation) then there is only one column and then everything ends in `row.name` as you experience.

Comment: If that's the real CSV content, it's invalid. Or rather, not what you think it is. What you posted is a *single* quoted text cell per line, containing text with commas

Comment: In any case you don't need Pandas to import flat files or CSVs to any database. You can use each database's bulk import commands, eg the `bcp` tool or `BULK INSERT` command in SQL Server. Pandas can't automagically fix bad input either, you'd have to read that file as a text file, remove the surrounding quotes from each. line and only then try to load it into pandas

Comment: If you have a valid CSV file you can use the [bcp](https://pypi.org/project/bcp/) or [bcpy](https://pypi.org/project/bcpy) packages to import the data directly into the server without caching it in a Dataframe

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos That was the case. The committed file was corrupted and added additionally double quotes. I recreated the file again and now it works as it should. thank you all for helping me

Comment: Make sure you try `bcp` or `bcpy`. Right now you're caching the data in memory before sending it to the database for no benefit. For large files this actually *slows* the import as the program has to load the data into memory before sending it to the server